# How do you back up a RAID 5 server?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, samba

I see many information on how to back up single drive, transfer information, or even use the dd command.

Originally, I had a 1 disk server, and when I migrated it to a higher end server, I went ahead and just used clonezilla.

Now, lets say I have a samba server configured using a raid 5 set up and I want to move it to another server and that server also has brand new drives as well. I know I can not just clone zilla since there are multiple drives.

So, what would be the best method to back up a raid 5 server and transfer it to another upgraded server

Answer (score 1):

The servers will mange RAID themselves. Just move the data however you want. CAUTION: Ensure the path length of the new server is equal to or less than the file path of the originating server. Users always create directory structures that reach the path length limit, so moving them to a location with even a single character more in the path can cause issues. Also, RAID is not a backup. Be sure to use a proper backup solution with a recovery window in line with your business requirements. Six months isn't unusual.

I'd go with a sync tool. Here are some free ones. DD is going to move everything, even the free space, so I always move data at the file level. You could also use rsync which may be an even better option for you.

http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-folder-synchronization-utility.htm http://www.readynas.com/download/documentation/support/rsync_howto_nastonas.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to set up the new server, then **schedule a maintenance window** for turning off normal users' access to the old server. During the maintenance window, **use a file copying tool** to copy everything you want to keep from the old server to the new one. Once the copying process completes, optionally do a verify step (something like a recursive md5sum on both and diff'ing the results should do nicely) before replacing the old server with the new one. Decomission the old server (and particularly its storage devices) as required by applicable procedures and regulations.

Incidentally, **this has nothing to do with whether you are using RAID or not.** RAID is simply a convenient method of, among other things, gaining storage redundancy. As a side-effect, [it tends to make whole-disk copying (through tools like dd, ddrescue etc) less useful](https://serverfault.com/q/639742/58408). That latter is already not very useful if you are migrating to disks of a different size, as the partitions would remain the same size on the target media; it is most useful when a disk is experiencing trouble. The whole point of a redundant RAID configuration (that is, essentially everything except RAID 0) is generally to reduce the likelihood of such troubles having any detrimental effect on user access to data.

And while you're at it, consider migrating to **RAID 6 (or 1+0) rather than RAID 5.** [Single redundancy just doesn't really cut it with today's drive sizes.](https://serverfault.com/a/118266/58408) Some people even predict [RAID 5's rapid demise](http://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/), in large part [because of that](https://superuser.com/q/912673/53590). You get better disk space utilization with [RAID 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_6), but [RAID 1+0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels#RAID_10_.28RAID_1.2B0.29) can generally give better performance.

Oh, and **you *are* already backing up the files on that server, aren't you?** Because if you aren't, then [you should start there rather than worrying about RAID this-or-that](https://serverfault.com/q/2888/58408). We regularly get questions here about how to recover important files that people didn't have backups of; *don't* become one of them. Even more so if these files aren't your personal files, but things people need to do their work.

Answer (score 0):

A RAID is operating-system and software transparent since it happens on a firmware / driver level. As far as any software is concerned, a RAID is just one drive. You should be able to just back up the partitions with a standard backup utility (like clonezilla) and throw them up on the new server as-is.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference that it is a raid 5 for these purposes.  The raid 5 is to treat multiple drives as if they are only one drive.  The software won't care.  I don't know about clonezilla.  I have done this with Ghost over the network.  If clonezilla has an option to copy one computer to another over the network, this would be ideal.  The only issue might be that you will have to have the proper drivers for the raid if cloning/ghosting software does not support it automatically.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!! so, if I just did a df -h, I would only see 1 drive i.e. /etc/sda? or would I see sda sdb sdc sdd sde ....etc

Comment: Assuming you are using hardware raid (i.e. you have to hit a special key combination when the computer is starting to configure raid) then yes, it will appear as just one drive.