# Why is there an "8 bay" limit on Seagate Ironwolf and WD Red NAS drives

Tags: raid, nas, compatibility

I just purchased a Synology DS918+ and have installed four 8TB Seagate Ironwolf drives.

One reason I chose the DS918 was the potential for future expandability using the DX 517 which provides 5 additional bays.  My thought was that when I needed the added storage I could move from my 4-drive RAID 5 configuration to a 9-drive RAID 6 configuration.

However, I just noticed that the promotional material for Seagate Ironwolf includes the phrase "up to 8 bays".

WD Red drives carry a similar statement: "built for single-bay to 8-bay NAS systems."

I don't know whether this will prevent me from a 9-drive RAID configuration.  Is this a physical "enclosure" limit based on the vibration dampening?   Or is it a firmware limit on optimizing RAID that won't work for a 9th drive?  Or is there some other limitation?

Comment: Please don't use RAID5 - it only provides an illusion of backup.

Comment: IronWolf may have discovered that larger single-box arrays resulted in more vibration and/or heat.  The best source for a specific manufacturer is their support line - ask them why they worded the ad copy this way.

Comment: I doubt it can be to do with a firmware limit - data strives are not privy to what other drives in the array are doing.

Comment: @davidgo can you point me to a link (preferably a stack exchange answer) amplifying your statement?

Comment: @DanielWiddis Which statement ?  Re my doubt about firmware -  Sorry, nope, its like trying to prove a negative.I know that the S in SATA means serial, and I've worked with hard disks, block devices and (mainly software) RAID long enough to understand the relationship between the bits.  It helps my case that the DS918+ is Linux Software RAID and I understand this -  https://serverfault.com/questions/568166/how-to-recover-an-mdadm-array-on-synology-nas-with-drive-in-e-state .

Comment: Re RAID5 - here is a starting point - https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/  This has been discussed to death here and on Serverfault.

Comment: @davidgo the one about RAID5. You've said "don't use" but have given me nothing to clarify why, or what a better alternative is.

Comment: We posted at about the same time.  RAID6 is OK for now, RAID10 is normally the best bet.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/912673/are-raid-5-systems-suitable-for-larger-disk-sizes/912741#912741

Comment: Thanks. Currently these drives *are* one of multiple backups and I insisted on RAID 5 over my housemate's statement that RAID 0 was sufficient. I'll look into 6 or even 10 (although with only 9 bays I guess I'm stuck with an 8 bay limit anyway...)

Comment: @DanielWiddis - The limitation of "only 8 drives" is only due to the fact, Seagate wants to sell more expensive HDDs to Enterprises that require 9+ drives in RAID, 9 drives will run fine in your DS918+.  *The amount of vibration that 8 drives will generate vs 9 drives won't be measurable.*

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research, I have determined that it is enclosure-based due to something called "rotational vibration" (RV).

[Synology's blog](https://blog.synology.com/xmas-wishlist-why-choose-nas-drives-over-desktop-drives-for-your-nas/) states:

> Closely nested drives operating at the same time inside a NAS can
>   result in vibration, noise, and heat. In addition, hard drives usually
>   have high spindle speeds (RPM) so that disks can rotate at a faster
>   speed and read data faster. Low spindle speeds create less vibration
>   and noise, but they become a hindrance to achieving better read/write
>   performance. Vibration is especially undesirable in multi-bay or rack
>   systems, for it hampers stability of hard drive operation and even
>   leads to data loss.

Seagate documents describe [AgileArray](https://blog.seagate.com/business/ironwolfpro/):

> AgileArray delivers drive balancing by using dual-plane balance and
>   rotational vibration (RV) sensors...

Similarly, WD documents describe [Rotary Acceleration Feed Forward](http://products.wdc.com/library/other/2579-001079.pdf):

> Hard drive performance is degraded when a hard drive is exposed to
>   vibration induced by one or more of its neighbors in the chassis. This
>   induced vibration shakes the head off a track that is currently being
>   read from or written to, resulting in retries and serious performance
>   consequences.

Accordingly, it appears having two separate enclosures (4-drive and 5-drive) won't approach this design specification.